# Restricting Table to one Row Only Access database

Tags: ms-access

I have created a table which holds a date range like startdate and  enddate.This is then referred to in query for the date criteria through a Dlookup. The table is filled through a form which is bound to this table.The problem now is if I change the dates,it creates another record in the table and this creates chaos on the query.How do I ensure that there is only one row in the table?

Comment: Hi CNM. I suggest you post some of the Access code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one record in table then edit existing record, don't enter dates into New Record row. Set form AllowAdditions and AllowDeletions properties to No.

Could instead of saving dates to a table, keep form open and have report reference form controls for criteria. This would also eliminate DLookup. Domain aggregate functions can slow performance.